# Detect redirect in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I may be asking the wrong question here so I will provide a small amount of detail about what I am trying to accomplish.

I use a third party web app to track support tickets. They provide the code for a form that my users fill out and it submits to their domain. I want to use this form on two different domains, but unfortunately the third party uses a single, hard coded redirect value. This causes one of my sites to switch domains after submission.

I was thinking I could embed their form in an iFrame, detect the redirection on successful form submission and instead redirect to one of my own pages.

Pseudocode:

```
iframe.detectRedirection
if (redirect == 'xyz.html') {  
     //do my own redirection in main window.
}
```

So back to my original question - how can I detect the redirection in the iframe?

Comment: maybe you can bind the form submit event using jquery, handle the form submission yourself and check the response code?

Comment: @RetoAebersold - great idea, I actually thought of this myself. But the form submits attachments so I can't send it via AJAX instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try

```
$("iframe").load(function(){
    //The iframe has loaded or reloaded. 
});
```

to detect the frame loading and refreshing

and if the redirect happens on the second load

```
//var to count times iframe has loaded
var timesRefreshed = 0;

//detect iframe loading/refreshing
$("iframe").load(function(){

    //if second refresh, change frame src - ie dont count first load
    if(timesRefreshed == 1){
        $(this).attr("src","my site url here");
    }

    //add to times resreshed counter
    timesRefreshed++; 

});
```

if there are more stages just change the x to the amount of stages

```
if(timesRefreshed == x)
```

this isnt full proof. ie if could break if the other site adds a stage etc but its the best i can think of if you dont have any control over the other site.

Comment: Is there an event that fires earlier than load? I tried `ready`, but it did not trigger. Unfortunately the iframe loads the whole other website before the `load` event triggers so it doesn't look very nice.

Comment: Hmm, also hitting x-domain origin policy problems. I guess this is why you chose to go by the number of times refreshed?

Comment: Yup. The only way i can think of is counting refreshes as the site in the iframe is on another domain thus you will have no access to it for security reasons. ill have a play and get back to you.

Comment: Right, ready gets fired when the iframe is ready. so will only ever fire once per top page load. Sorry but i think this is your only option. Unless you can change where the frame redirects to.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the additional feedback. This does seem to be the best client side solution given my restrictions.