# AngularJS: count number of redirect in iframe?

Tags: angularjs

How can i count number of times the iframe has redirect with AngularJS?

I do so far with [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23948165), but no luck.

I found if using JQuery can done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924558/973530).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tried approach like this one?You could probably do almost the same with Angular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301193/detect-redirect-in-iframe

Comment: It's will be easy if using JQuery, but i struggle with AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i get the answer, this the code:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $window) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $window.iframeLoaded = function () {
        console.log('value of i: '+i);
        if(i === 1) {
            // something todo
        }
        i++;
    };
  });
})
```

Html:

```
<iframe  ng-src="{{frameUrl}}" onLoad="iframeLoaded()">
    Something was wrong!.
</iframe>
```